# Broadcast confidential data

Tags: c#, security

I need to broadcast a confidential data (a simple string) on the network (via socket, wcf, web services, not very matter how the way).

Well, I've just created a serializable class with an encrypted string and just one method to decrypt it which return decrypted data.

Is it a good solution to implement? Or maybe I'll never should include in my object "the decrypt method" for an serialized object relayed on the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the way it's done then why not just put the receiving end as a web service with an HTTPS certificate? That way you don't have to care about encryption or decryption or key exchange.

If you don't want to do that then it's sent over the wire via the methods you listed it's just going to be a message containing property values - code doesn't get sent. If someone sniffs it, and doesn't have access to your classes, and your encryption is sound you'll be ok.

Comment: Because I'm trying to implement a simple solution by myself..And I'd understand the right way to accomplish it..

Comment: If you're being simple then, and this isn't for production I'd create a helper class which does the encrypt and decrypt and include that in both projects. When an object is serialized and sent it's usually a message, there are not methods attached to it, so treat it as such.

Comment: Ok, but my question is still alive: can contained instruction in some method be discovered by someone? when an object is serialized, can it be discoevered through the network?